# ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver always returns 200 response code in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have upgraded from Spring 4.2 to Spring 5.0.5. After upgrading my junits are failing with the below error.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Testing return value. expected:<405> but was:<200>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
at
```

Below is my code:

```
`package com.hp.ci.mgmt.controllers;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import 
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException;
import
```

org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonLocation;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException;


public class AbstractBaseControllerTest extends AbstractBaseController
{
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver resolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

private MockHttpServletRequest request;
private MockHttpServletResponse response;

@Mock
CiException cie;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Before
public void setup()
{
    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConvertersList = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConvertersList.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    resolver.setMessageConverters(messageConvertersList);
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.when(cie.getErrorSource()).thenReturn("test");
}

@Test
public void testUnsupportedOperationException()
        throws Exception
{
    validateException(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, new RequestNotAllowedException());
}

private void validateException(final HttpStatus expectedStatus, final 
Exception e)
        throws Exception
{
    validateExceptionStatus(expectedStatus, e);        
}

 private void validateExceptionStatus(final HttpStatus expectedStatus, final Exception e)
        throws Exception
{
    resolver.resolveException(request, response, this, e);
    if (expectedStatus == null)
    {
        assertEquals("Testing return value.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), response.getStatus());
    }
    else
    {
        assertEquals("Testing return value.", expectedStatus.value(), response.getStatus());
    }

}
```

Issue is that the below code always returns 200 status code, therefore all my tests fail.

resolver.resolveException(request, response, this, e);

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found what is causing the issue. Looks like "this" in the below line does not extend HandlerMethod so resolveException returns null without doing anything.

resolver.resolveException(request, response, this, e);

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldApplyTo(HttpServletRequest request, @Nullable Object 
handler) {
    if (handler == null) {
        return super.shouldApplyTo(request, null);
    }
    else if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        handler = handlerMethod.getBean();
        return super.shouldApplyTo(request, handler);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with configuring the handler. How can i implement HandlerMethod?